# Juju - Can't enter in the wordpress public address

Tags: juju, maas

I am using ubuntu 14.04.2 server and have 3 nodes. One for the juju-gui, mysql and wordpress.

At first I had this situation

[image]

After that, I did the following:

juju add-relation wordpress mysql

juju add-unit wordpress

juju expose wordpress

At first, on the wordpress situation I got 2 bars, one yellow and one red " hook failed: install ", to solve this I selected wordpress charm and did "Resolve" and did the trick.

[image]

Because I did : juju add-unit wordpress, seems like it added another machine.

[image]

Then I did juju terminate-machine 3, and so:

[image]

But now I want to enter in the wordpress node, 172.16.1.133 (node3.maas) it says the webpage is not available! 
How do I solve this?
Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: Clicking resolve in the GUI as you did you're actually telling Juju that the issue has been resolved not telling it to resolve the issue.

It's hard to debug why Wordpress isn't working in this case without actually poking at it but the failure to add the new unit may have put the charm in a broken state which hasn't actually been resolved (see above). So your first step might be to SSH into `node2.maas` and see if Wordpress is indeed running and if you're able to access it from within the machine. If it is running you might have a separate networking issue. If it's not running you can try removing Wordpress and bringing up a fresh machine to deploy it to and see if your issue is resolved.